# How to check which action method rendered the current view (from within the current view)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to know how to check which action displayed the current View (from the current view).

For instance, to check if controller myController originated the rendering (I guess) I can write:

```
<% if(ViewContext.Controller is myApplication.Controllers.myController)%>
```

In fact, I want to use the same View model for 2 actions methods, like this:

```
<% If( First Action rendered this view){%> 
   // Display this 
<%} else {%> 
   //Display that 
<%}%>
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use ***ViewData*** for storing name of Action from which view is being rendered

OR

Use `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]` for pulling out the action name out of ***RouteData***

Comment: Better would be to put which type of display the action wishes the view to perform. Otherwise, it all feels a bit backwards.

Comment: @Damien - You might be right. But, I've 2 relatively close input operations to do. I just want to use 1 view model, hiding a couple unecessary information at time.

Answer (score 3):

use `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]`